# mixed installation - how to remove older version of openscenegraph

Tags: 13.10, uninstall

I'm trying to solve an issue [osg_forum](http://forum.openscenegraph.org/viewtopic.php?t=13571&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0)  with openscenegraph and I found out that
I have 2 versions of openscenegraph installed (dont know how it happened).

I would like to uninstall both of them and reinstall

One of them I just removed with

```
sudo make uninstall
```

called from build folder and it removed /usr/local/lib64 libraries, includes etc..

And I dont know how to remove the other one which is located in
/usr/lib.
I dont have any "build folder" where I could use make uninstall and

```
sudo apt-get remove openscenegraph
```

doesnt do the job ( I just noticed that it removed osgmovie bin for example..)
Is it save to just delete it?

Because when I want to play movie using osgmovie then it loads /usr/lib/osgPlugin.ffmpeg.so and not /usr/local/lib64/osgPlugin.ffmpeg.so and I really dont want to "mess" with these libraries even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openscenegraph
```